# How to include base class without implementing pure virtual functions?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, include, virtual-functions

I have a class A that has objects of type C, D, E, F, etc. in it, all of which inherit the base class B. I am trying to include the header for class B, but my code won't compile since I have a pure virtual function in B

Classes of type C, D, E, F, etc override the virtual function, but including the class B header in the class A header to allow for `std::vector<B> objects;` causes an issue. Is there any way around this? I know I can make the function not virtual, but I want to keep the base class as is and be able to use the name in class A for polymorphism

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> objects;
// ...
}
```

B.h:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
// ...
}
```

Comment: Should it be a vector of pointers to B? You can't create objects of type B to populate the vector.

Comment: It's not the inclusion. You can't have a `vector<T>` if `T` is an abstract type.

Comment: In C++, polymorphic objects *requires* the use of pointers (including smart pointers) or references.  You cannot have polymorphism in C++ otherwise.